# How to get embedded Lua syntax highlighting with g:vimsyn_embed='l' to work in Neovim 0.9.5?

Tags: neovim, init.vim

I created a test file by launching Neovim using `nvim --clean test.vim`, then verified the filetype was `vim` using `set ft`. Then I set `let g:vimsyn_embed='l'`. However the following file is still highlighted incorrectly:

```
lua << EOF
  local lspconfig = require('lspconfig')
  lspconfig.pyright.setup {}
  lspconfig.tsserver.setup {}
  lspconfig.rust_analyzer.setup {}
EOF
```

Do I need to do something else to get `g:vimsyn_embed` to work? I read that it worked for other people a few years ago (https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/j3xmf3/how_can_i_highlight_lua_code_in_a_usual_vim_file/) and that this option was even enabled by default in 2021 (https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/14213).

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to get `g:vimsyn_embed` to work, but here's what I did instead:

1. Install [nvim-treesitter](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter).
2. In `~/.config/nvim/after/queries/vim/injections.scm`, put:

```
; extends
(lua_statement
  (script
    (body) @injection.content)
  (#set! injection.language "lua"))
```

The comment is required. Otherwise the file will override your Treesitter configuration instead of extending it.

I'm happy to accept another answer if someone actually gets `g:vimsyn_embed` to work.

Comment: Injection of Lua highlight from vimscript is configured by default in nvim-treesitter, so I think you don't need step 2 here. Just install nvim-treesitter and it should work out of box.

Comment: It doesn’t work out of the box for me on the stable release or on HEAD.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug of **vim** syntax engine and syntax file (hence neovim shares the same issue): https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/20456

Using treesitter for Vimscript and Lua syntax highlighting will be much recommended.

Comment: vim isn’t installed on my computer.

Comment: You got it wrong. I mean, neovim inherits from vim, so the bug of vim also affects neovim. Read the issue.

Comment: It's not only a bug of Vim, but also a bug of Neovim. And a patch would be appreciated :)